# Can i Create the Paging user control for gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi please give me idea or reference to create Paging User control.

Thank You very much in advance.

Comment: ASP.NET already have a control you can use to create a pager if that's what you mean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx

Comment: What do you want to do with a User Control that the GridView's pager won't do?

Comment: I think maybe he wants to add to the functionality or customize it in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya i have created User control for the gridview using delegates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom pager, you could start by using this paged list implementation to take care of the bulk of the work for you, and then you can just focus on the UI.

http://www.squaredroot.com/2009/06/15/return-of-the-pagedlist/